# Prometheus target endpoint IP location

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

I have a question, i deployed my Prometheus on k8s cluster and integrated it with istio to push metrics of my application pods. But in the targets page i see some endpoint URLs having ips which are not POD ips or Service ips as below
[image]

What is that ip and the port?

Comment: Is that a node IP? If so, you might have some weird deployment with hostNetwork mode?

Comment: No that's not my host ip.

Comment: Are you using Prometheus Operator? If so, you can probably trace it back to a ServiceMonitor object and look at the selector.

Comment: Based on [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/ops/deployment/requirements/#ports-used-by-istio) it's might be IP of  `Citadel, Citadel agent, Galley, Mixer, Istiod, Sidecar Injector`. Could you use `kubectl get ep -n istio-system` and check there? For me it's istio-pilot endpoint which in version 1.5.0 is part of istiod. What is your istio version?

Comment: My pilot endpoint is `istio-pilot          192.168.4.16:15014` and the my istio version is 1.3.2

Comment: Is there, in the endpoints results, the IP you're looking for? 192.168.140.70:15014?

Comment: No. There's not. Any other way to trace back to that IP from prometheus pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the IP of [citadel](https://istio.io/docs/ops/deployment/architecture/#citadel) pod deployed by istio. Citadel is an istio component which enables strong service-to-service and end-user authentication with built-in identity and credential management.You can check the citadel pod deployed in the namespace where you have deployed istio or in the `istio-system` namespace.

Comment: No, my citadel pod ip is 
`istio-citadel-77d8499bb9-klrk5                        1/1     Running     0          47h   192.168.4.18   k8s-worker-2`

Comment: what is the ip of mixer?

Comment: `istio-policy-f96cb4986-sl9wr  - 192.168.4.17
istio-telemetry-d74b7664d-58lnp - 192.168.4.13 `

Comment: so there is no pod in istio namespace which has this IP?

Comment: Yes. But i get this ips in the prometheus targets for citadel, envoy-stats etc.